# Facebook Login doesn't change to 'Logout" Option After Login

Tags: facebook

I was kind of expecting the Facebook Button to change and give the option of logging out, but after the user authorizes the application, nothing really changes in the button.

Did I misunderstand how the button is supposed to really work?

Thanks,

Comment: what platform is it? iOS, Android, Javascript, .net, C++, C, pascal, assembler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple.  This code does it:

The only thing I had to do differently to make the logout option show up is this:
autologoutlink="true"

Comment: is it iOS \ Android? where is this flag?